# There are no graphic controls for action creation in routines (only text field to type command)

Tags: google-smart-home

To create any routine, user needs to enter full command in the text field. Is it possible to add additional graphic controls that can help user in creating a routine? For example, to provide possibility to select any commands from predefined list, provided to the user based on SYNC request. Do you consider any similar possibility or “browse popular actions” option is provided for this purpose? Could you please clarify if additional actions can be added to “browse popular actions” option? Can user customize them and how exactly? Could you please provide the examples?

Comment: You can file feature requests for the platform here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148

Answer (score 0):

As a developer there are no ways to add additional actions to the list. However, For specific types of actions, like controlling lights or thermostats, those devices will be surfaced and controlled through a specific set of controls.